# How do I create an event for a user from android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to allow the user to create an event using the facebook android sdk?

Comment: An event like the one  you normally create on the facebook account eg: a birthday party, a music concert , a wedding ..

Comment: ok, and how much you tried about these kind of event ?

Comment: I know I can get info about the events using me/events in an async runner. But I cannot find any documentation on the graph api on how to create one(developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/). If you do know some link please post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already posted the correct link to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) in the comments. Just follow this link for the call you are searching for:

> To create an event on behalf of a User: instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events)

Comment: Oh-I completely missed that. Let me go through it.